# onScreen plugin not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to use the [onScreen() plugin](http://silvestreh.github.io/onScreen/index.html) to control items when they enter or leave viewport (visible part of the screen). As a test a tried to add this line `$(".block").fadeIn(6000);` to "doIn" but it doesn't work. Is there a syntax issue or something? See http://jsfiddle.net/8E4FA/ Thanks

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('elements').onScreen({
           container: window,
           direction: 'vertical',
           doIn: function() {
               $(".block").fadeIn(6000);
           },
           doOut: function() {
               // Do something to the matched elements as they get off scren
           },
           tolerance: 0,
           throttle: 50,
           toggleClass: 'onScreen',
           lazyAttr: null,
           lazyPlaceholder: 'someImage.jpg',
           debug: false
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Syntax error are easy to see in the console.

Comment: Please create a fiddle

Comment: Hi - just did, see http://jsfiddle.net/8E4FA/ Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the plugin developer. You were using the sample code from the plugin's site, meaning you had no matched elements using the `$("elements")` selector. I changed the selector to `$(".block")` and got rid of all the default values.

Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8E4FA/1/

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I ran it with `try` and `catch` and it turns out:

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

My best guess is that you put the reference to the `onScreen` plugin before the JQuery reference, try reversing them.

However, I have a better guess that you did not include `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">` in your HTML.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but issue must be somewhere else. I've just created a jsfiddle if it helps http://jsfiddle.net/8E4FA/ Thanks

Comment: @Greg At the end of your code, see what happens when you put `alert($('elements').onScreen);`